# How can you rename a key in a JSON nested object at all levels?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "ID": "5c9b2de495e8d81ef437539e",
  "WeightingFactor": "BIC",
  "TargetAmount": 1000,
  "FilterCondition": {
    "_cls": "ComplexFilter",
    "Condition": "AND",
    "Rules": [{
        "_cls": "Filter",
        "Field": "MOODYSFOREIGNCURRENCYCEILINGRATING",
        "Operator": "in list",
        "Value": "A1,A2,A3"
      },
      {
        "_cls": "Filter",
        "Field": "ASOFDATE",
        "Operator": "less or equal",
        "Value": "26 Nov 2028"
      },
      {
        "_cls": "ComplexFilter",
        "Condition": "OR",
        "Rules": [{
            "_cls": "Filter",
            "Field": "ASOFDATE",
            "Operator": "less or equal",
            "Value": "26 Nov 2028"
          },
          {
            "_cls": "Filter",
            "Field": "ASOFDATE",
            "Operator": "less or equal",
            "Value": "26 Nov 2029"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Not": false
  }
}
```

Need to rename `"field"` to `category` everywhere. Kindly suggest how is it possible using any available methods ?

Tried `stringify` and `replace`. But it's not working

Expected output :

```
{
  "ID": "5c9b2de495e8d81ef437539e",
  "WeightingFactor": "BIC",
  "TargetAmount": 1000,
  "FilterCondition": {
    "_cls": "ComplexFilter",
    "Condition": "AND",
    "Rules": [{
        "_cls": "Filter",
        "Category": "MOODYSFOREIGNCURRENCYCEILINGRATING",
        "Operator": "in list",
        "Value": "A1,A2,A3"
      },
      {
        "_cls": "Filter",
        "Category": "ASOFDATE",
        "Operator": "less or equal",
        "Value": "26 Nov 2028"
      },
      {
        "_cls": "ComplexFilter",
        "Condition": "OR",
        "Rules": [{
            "_cls": "Filter",
            "Category": "ASOFDATE",
            "Operator": "less or equal",
            "Value": "26 Nov 2028"
          },
          {
            "_cls": "Filter",
            "Category": "ASOFDATE",
            "Operator": "less or equal",
            "Value": "26 Nov 2029"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Not": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could replace the strings `"field":` with `"category":` in the given [JSON](https://json.org/) string.

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({ field: { field: 'foo' } }),
    newJSON = json.replace(/"field":/g, '"category":');

console.log(JSON.parse(newJSON));
```

A classical replacement

```js
function replace(object, source, target) {
    return Object.assign(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({
        [k === source ? target : k]: v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? replace(v, source, target)
            : v
    })));
}

var object = { field: { field: 'foo' } },
    newObject = replace(object, 'field', 'category');

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: @AlexanderRuliov, right. but is it likely to have quotes in keys?

Comment: Ohh, already added the classical approach :)
My answer is irrelevant now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a performance test on Regex replacing a key vs deep traversing a JSON object and replacing a key and it turns out the Regex way is 65% slower than the deep traversal approach.

Here is the code to do it the deep traversal way :

```
function deepTraverseAndReplace(o,sk,rk) {
    for (var key in o) {
        if (o[key ] !== null && typeof(o[key])=="object") {
            traverse(o[key],sk,rk);
        } else if( key == sk ) {
            o[rk] = o[key];
            delete(o[key]);
        }
    }
}



deepTraverseAndReplace(jsonObj,'Field','Category')
```

Here is the link of the create [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-deep-traversing/1)

Comment: this is a mutating approach. why not.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a non-mutating solution, so thought this would be fine.